# Can it be said that $\sum_{k=n}^{\infty} q^{k} = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} q^{n} \cdot q^{k}$?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, geometric-series

I would like to know if the following equality is always true for geometric series.

$$\sum_{k=n}^{\infty} q^{k} = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} q^{n} \cdot q^{k}$$

It has worked for me on several occasions, for example:

$$  \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} 45 \cdot \left(\frac{25}{36}\right)^{k} =
  \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} 45 \cdot \left(\frac{25}{36}\right)^{1} \cdot \left(\frac{25}{36}\right)^{k}  $$

$$  \sum_{k=2}^{\infty} 45 \cdot \left(\frac{25}{36}\right)^{k} =
  \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} 45 \cdot \left(\frac{25}{36}\right)^{2} \cdot \left(\frac{25}{36}\right)^{k}  $$

So, can lower limits be safely shifted with this method?

Thanks!

Comment: Yes. Hint $q^{n+k}=q^{n}q^{k}$.

Comment: Write out the first few terms.  You’ll note that by rules of exponents you can factor out a $q^n$.  The resulting series is geometric starting at index 0.  You are correct

Comment: Yes, more generally $\sum_{k=n}^\infty f(k)=\sum_{k=0}^\infty f(k+n)$

Comment: Are you familiar with index changes?